# XMLHttpResponse object loads same content on every call to open()

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm trying to monitor the position of my vehicle in real time. 
I'm using the googlemaps API to do this. 
My objective is to constantly update the marker (position of my car) every three seconds without having to reload the entire map.

The vehicle's current location is saved in 'vehicle_location.txt'.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Car Location</title>
    <style>
    /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
     * element that contains the map. */
     #map {
      height: 100%;
     }
    /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
    html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
    var map;
    var markers = [];
    var timerId;
    var contents;

    function initMap() {
    ``var initial_location = {lat: 15.3647, lng: 75.1240};
    //timerId = setInterval(update_map,3000);
    update_map();
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 12,
      center: initial_location,
    });
    addMarker(initial_location);
  }

  // Adds a marker to the map and push to the array.
  function addMarker(location) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location,
      map: map
    });
    markers.push(marker);
  }

  // Sets the map on all markers in the array.
  function setMapOnAll(map) {
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      markers[i].setMap(map);
    }
  }

  // Removes the markers from the map, but keeps them in the array.
  function clearMarkers() {
    setMapOnAll(null);
  }

  // Shows any markers currently in the array.
  function showMarkers() {
    setMapOnAll(map);
  }

  // Deletes all markers in the array by removing references to them.
  function deleteMarkers() {
    clearMarkers();
    markers = [];
  }

  //Updates map every 3 seconds
  function update_map(){
    //read_file();
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.onreadystatechange = function() 
    {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) 
        {
            alert(this.responseText);
            timerId = setTimeout('update_map()', 3000);
        }
    };
    //req.addEventListener("load", reqListener);
    req.open("GET", "./vehicle_location.txt", true);
    req.send(null);

  } 

</script>
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?     key=YOUR_APIKEY_HERE&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

The problem is, `'this.responseText`' has same value on every call to

`req.open("GET", "./vehicle_location.txt", true)`

inspite of the text file constantly changing.

I am new to js. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Then the other handle (software) that is supposed to update `vehicle_location.txt` is failing to do so. It could be also browser cache

Comment: @AdamAzad, the software is working fine. The contents of the 'vehicle_location.txt' file are changing constantly. If it is browser cache, how can i clear it dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the software is constantly updating `vehicle_location.txt` with no issues. Then, it could be browser cache. To override this, the simplest method is adding a random query to target URL, so browser identifies it as a new URL; thus, ignoring cache. The most commonly used is a timestamp.

```
var ts = new Date().getTime(); // output a unix timestamp reflecting the current date and time. 
req.open("GET", "./vehicle_location.txt?t="+ts, true);
```

The above will generate a new URL with every new XHR request issued like:

```
./vehicle_location.txt?t=1483349217755
./vehicle_location.txt?t=1483349217757
./vehicle_location.txt?t=1483349217759
./vehicle_location.txt?t=1483349217760
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks. Also found a [document](http://www.labbookpages.co.uk/web/realtime.html) which says something along similar lines.